# Nim game question

Tags: java, variable-assignment

OK, I have to make a nim game and try to find the strategy to always win with the following nim game:

21 matches, player 1 and 2 each take 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 matches each turn, and one cannot take the same amount of matches the previous player takes. Th eplayer wins if/when they take the last match.

I have to program something for this, but I don't even understand were to start. How can i find the winning strategy with this type of nim game?

EDIT:

So I figured you'll always win when you get to 7 matches still in the middle. The other can take 2-5 and you can add up to 7 taking the last one. when the other takes 1, you take 3 (the other can't take 3 as well then) and has to pick 1 or 2 in which case you'll get the alst one and win as well.

However, going from 21 to 7 is a puzzle for me i cant figure out how you can always be the person getting to 7.

EDIT 2: 
ok so without the rule that you can't take the same as the previous player it is quite simple i think.

You'd make k = 5 + 1 = 6. then you should make the first move such that the matches left then % 6 = 0. So in this case take 3 first and then afterwards fill up the move of the other player to 6. However in this case that won't work because the other player can take 3 after which you can't take 3 to fill up to 6. So there is my problem. Any ideas?

EDIT3:

ok so you say I can force 7 matches. However suppose I take the same thinking to the 14-7 matches step. (it then is the other's turn)

there are two scenarios then: 
1: he takes 2-5 and I fill it up to seven which let 7 there and I win.
2: he takes 1, so there are 13 left. When i take 3 as i do in the (7-0)-step it becomes 10. Then he takes 5 and i can't take 5 anymore to finish and i will loose.

Here lies the problem, where scenario 2 is no problem in the (7-0)-step it is now. How do I solve this?

YES, THE SOLUTION:

btw, na speler 1 means: after player 1's turn etc (I'm dutch).

[image]

Ok so i tried some things and i think i have the solution. You have to take 1 match as the first player first. Then the other guys can take 2-5 matches. You match (pun intended) his amount up to 7 so you'll have (21-1-7=) 13 matches left in the middle always. Then it is Player 2's turn again and there are two scenarios: player 2 takes 1,2,4,or5 matches, in which case you take as much matches that there will be 7 in the left. (as told earlier when you take matches such that there are 7 left you'll always win). The second scenario is that player 2 takes 3 matches in which case there are 10 in the middle when it is your turn. You can't take 3 to make 7 because you can't take 2 times the same amount. So you take 5 so there are 5 left. Player 2 then can't take 5 to win and has to pick 1-4 after which you can take the remaining ones and win.

This is the solution i guess. I somehow came onto it because i noticed this:

Normal Nim game with modulo etc:

```
P2  1  2  3  4  5  
P1  5  4  3  2  1  
------------------
    6  6  6  6  6
```

But you cant do 3,3 here so it is liek this:

```
p2 1  2  3  4  5 
p1    5  4  3  2  1
---------------------
      7  7  7  7
```

So you can make 7 everytime and 1 is a special case. I don't know why but i intuitively took 1 as starting point as it feels like you need to take initiative to be able to control the other's moves. (one cannot do two times 1 so the other has to take 2-5 which makes you in control)

Anyway, THANKS a lot for all the help. Also for the whole program that was written. I couldn't use it because it wouldn't compile as a lack good java skills :) and i also wanted to solve it myself.

Anyway, i saw this is a wiki, good luck for people in the future trying to solve this!

Comment: This doesn't immediately strike me as a programming question.  Deriving the winning strategy for this game doesn't have anything to do with Java, *per se*.  Unless, I suppose, you wanted to do some kind of statistical simulation and try to work out the strategy from the results of random games.  But you can actually infer it through logic, with no computers involved.

Comment: Also, you've said you "have to program something for this".  What is the something?  Why does it **have** to be a program?  If it's for an assignment, chances are you had a much more specific brief than "program something", so perhaps inspecting that will lead you down the right tracks.  If it's your own personal choice for a project, I'm afraid you picked an unsuitable project.

Comment: I have tofind the solution, the best strategy that will alwyas win. And i couldn't figure it out afetr hours of thinking and google so i now want to try to programm something that solves it in java. However if you have any tips on how to find it or reason towards it without java i'd be very happy too!

Comment: @Javaaaa: When you program, you're telling a computer what to do. That requires you knowing what to do yourself! So you need to know the strategy yourself before you can tell a computer how to do that strategy. Although there are general techniques for this sort of thing in the AI field that prevent you from needing to know EVERYTHING about a complicated game, for a game like this it's much faster to look for the strategy yourself. See my answer for a few hints, and feel free to comment with questions or requests for clarification if you need to.

Comment: Spoiler alert: there is tons of information on solving nim games in the nim article on wikipeida.

Comment: @Javaaaa: +1 to your question for actually taking the time to think it through and trying to learn something. :-)

Comment: @Javaaaa: Like I said in a comment to my answer, if you can go from 7 to 0 then you have a way of reliably subtracting 7. So work backwards, using that fact. :-)

Comment: @Platinum - a slight correction (and a tiny spoiler, perhaps) really you're looking at going from 7 to **1** rather than to 0.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle: Normally I'm of that school when I play Nim myself, but if you read the original post you'll see that Javaaaa's requirements dictate that a win comes from taking the last match. You'll also see that moves cannot be repeated twice in a row. You are correct in noting that if the goal is NOT to take the last match, that's the same as being the player who knocks the counter down to 1. However, as the OP established, s/he can reliably knock it down by 7 over a couple of turns, so in reality the strategy would be to go from _8 to 1_.

Comment: Ah yes, reading fail on my part. :-/

Comment: @Javaaaa: One question: what is the result of not being able to move, while there are still sticks left?  (e.g. `5 4 5 3 2 1 ?`)

Comment: I wouldn't know, but that won't be an optimal strategy so you wouldnt play it like that i guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In games like this, you need to maintain the invariant of being in a winning position (if you're already in one). So you need to know how to start from a winning position, and then go back to it *no matter what move your opponent does*.

Here are three hints for you:

1. Your moveset, and your opponent's moveset, is the same: take 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 matches.
2. This game, when you get down to it, is an adding game. Yes, you're subtracting matches, but it still helps to think in terms of addition when you're formulating your strategy.
3. Start with this: For any opponent move X (where X is 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5), what move can you do to "cancel" that move out?

The concept I'm trying to go for is explained in the concept of [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), in case that helps.

---

**Edit:** The restriction on not taking the same number of matches makes things interesting, though. We'll have to address that as a corner case later, but let's first see how you come along with what I've said so far. Please feel free to comment on that.

---

**Edit 2:** You're correct with the second edit in general (if the rule about no repeated moves weren't there, I mean). But your first edit was on the right track: You can make things work in 7's.

Just keep questioning and answering yourself:

Q: How do I reliably force a win for the AI by making the AI take the last match?
A: Force the AI to leave 7 matches, then use your strategy to force the AI to take the 7th one left. This is because you can force exactly 7 matches to be subtracted.
Q: So how do I force a win for the AI by making sure the AI takes the last match (but seven)?

Don't overthink it. Take what you already know-- what you can already make the AI do-- and apply that step as many times as you can.

---

**Edit 3:** This is just a minor point I thought of that might help you deal with the problem you mention in your third edit.

If, for all X in the moveset (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), there remain 2X matches when it's the AI's turn, then you can force a win by taking X matches. (You detailed how, except with the other player, in your third edit)

Unfortunately, this isn't something you can force because I'm talking about there being 2X matches *before* the AI's turn, whereas the other strategy winning conditions are contingent on the position *after* the AI's turn, so that the AI's move can force it.

Similarly, you want to avoid having the AI's move result in 2X matches for any of those X.

Comment: I understand, however the fact that one cannot take the same amount of matches after the other becomes a problem when the other takes 3.

Comment: You figured out how to go from 7 to 0 and force that to be a winning solution. You can GUARANTEE that you can subtract 7, in other words. So now think backwards... If you can win when there are 7 matches left on the human player's turn (because you can force exactly 7 to be removed)... how can you force your way to 7?

Comment: I upvoted this because it addresses how a human might approach the game.  But I still believe that this isn't a game where you have to make the computer act like a human...a computer has no trouble exploring the entire game tree.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Thanks for the upvote. And I completely agree with you, but I feel that if this is a homework assignment for someone who might not have a lot of experience with the human reasoning needed to discover the right computer algorithms, then that reasoning should be developed as early as possible. But that's just my personal philosophy, I guess. Good thing I'm not a professor, right? ;-)

Comment: @ platinum, please check Second EDIT in OP. When that rule was not there it would be simple right? however how does it work with that rule? any ideas?

Comment: thanks again, I almost thought I had it however I still encounter a problem. any ideas on EDIT3?

Comment: Oh wow. I feel really dumb. I should have thought of that! This problem is getting more intriguing by the second. I'm sorry, now I'm (temporarily) stymied. Way to go for coming up with an interesting problem! Maybe instead of discussing this you should go with the Minimax algorithm mentioned by Mark Peters. :-)

Comment: Okay, my answer is way too exploratory and non-definitive at this point, so I've gone ahead and marked it community wiki. Anyone else who has any human-strategic ideas can contribute. This is too interesting of a problem, but I don't want to have the highest vote count or check mark for an answer that (at this point) does not fundamentally work. I don't want any more rep off of this because it feels a little dishonest. So I'm turning it over to the community. :-)

Comment: OK i think i have an answer. Maybe some math guys can back this up with binary thinking or something? (that's what i came accros with other Nim games (multiple stacks i guess) solutions)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Minimax algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), potentially with alpha-beta pruning if you need to cut down on the running time.

Essentially, you exhaustively search the tree of possible moves and then work back upwards to decide on the best result.

**Edit**: Here's some code to show you how easy it is to make a perfect agent.  It took about 5 minutes to code up.

```
public class MinimaxNim {

    public static int getBestMove(int matchesLeft, int lastVal) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int bestMove = matchesLeft > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        for ( int move = 1; move <= 5 && move <= matchesLeft; move++ ) {
            if ( move == lastVal )
                continue;
            int val = minValue(matchesLeft - move, move);
            if ( val > max ) {
                bestMove = move;
                max = val;
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }

    private static int maxValue(int matchesLeft, int lastVal) {
        if ( matchesLeft == 0 ) 
            return -1; //min has won

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for ( int toTake = 1; toTake <= 5 && toTake <= matchesLeft; toTake++) {
            if ( toTake == lastVal ) 
                continue;
            int val = minValue(matchesLeft - toTake, toTake);
            if ( val > max ) {
                max = val;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    private static int minValue(int matchesLeft, int lastVal) {
        if ( matchesLeft == 0 ) 
            return 1; //max has won

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for ( int toTake = 1; toTake <= 5 && toTake <= matchesLeft; toTake++) {
            if ( toTake == lastVal ) 
                continue;
            int val = maxValue(matchesLeft - toTake, toTake);
            if ( val < min ) {
                min = val;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

You could test with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 21;
    int move = -1;
    for ( ;; ) {
        move = getBestMove(count, move);
        System.out.println("Player 1 takes " + move);
        count -= move;
        if ( count == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 has won");
            break;
        }
        move = getBestMove(count, move);
        System.out.println("Player 2 takes " + move);
        count -= move;
        if ( count == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 has won");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I would suggest replacing either player 1 or player 2 with yourself, or a random agent, so that you examine the moves that a perfect player makes.

Again, this doesn't show you the best *strategy*, but it will exhibit optimal play against any opponent (though untested).

**Edit 2**

In case you're curious, from the initial state there are only 26705 terminal states (where a player has won) that need to be examined.  That gets less and less as you make more moves.  What makes this perfect for minimax is that progress is always made...once you're at 15 matches left in the pile, you can't go back to 17, e.g.  In a game like chess you can get cycles in the search tree since players can just dance around the board, returning to previous states, etc.

Comment: That's a good general strategy for any sort of AI development, but it's overkill for a simple game like this.

Comment: @Platinum: A perfect minimax agent for this can be written in about 40-50 lines of code.  In fact, for my AI course a nim game was the textbook example for teaching minimax.  It applies directly.  It doesn't address strategy as your answer does; it just recognizes that the number of possible game states is small so anything more complicated than an exhaustive search is probably overkill.

Comment: @Mark Peters: You don't even need an exhaustive strategy. Maybe you should also take a look at my answer and see if you can understand what I'm getting at. To me, this is more of an exercise in devising algorithms and learning to develop the intuition required for that, and teaching a beginner to look into AI is not going to be as useful at this point in his/her career.

Comment: @Platinum: I'm not saying you need one, I'm saying developing one is dead simple.  And while it may be in the domain of "AI", it's really just an algorithm.  Someone without any experience of AI can understand it.

Comment: +1 for a perfectly valid answer, even if I might disagree with applying it to this situation given the OP's apparent experience.

Comment: I'm liking this answer more and more with time. :-(

Comment: @Platinum: you should create an agent based on your heuristics, and we can play them against each other :-).  If your heuristic shows optimal play, it will always win if it gets to go first.

Comment: @ Mark Peters: thanks a lot for your help although i couldn't really use it myself, you're help is still very much appreciated!

Comment: @Javaaaa: No problem!  If nothing else, you can use my other answer as a way of double checking your strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Just as some more data to consider, I ran my agent against every possible scenario you could have in the game (1-21 sticks left times 5 possible last moves).  Some of these states are impossible (e.g. 20 with the last move being 2).  I removed most of these from the table but more probably remain.

If there is a value for that combination, it means that playing that move at that point will definitely result in a win (assuming continued perfect play).

Those marked with an x mean that being in that state will definitely result in a loss regardless of move (assuming the opponent's perfect play).

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5
21 1           
20   x         
19     3       
18   5 5 5     
17   4   4 5   
16   3 3 x 3 3 
15   2 1 1 1 1 
14   x 1 1 1 1 
13   x x x x x 
12   5 5 5 5 x 
11   4 4 4 x 4 
10   3 3 5 3 3 
 9   2 3 2 2 2 
 8   4 1 1 1 1 
 7   x x x x x 
 6   3 3 x 3 3 
 5   5 5 5 5 x 
 4   4 4 4 x 4 
 3   3 3 x 3 3 
 2   2 1 1 1 1 
 1   x 1 1 1 1
```

So if you're stuck doing analysis, you can lookup in this table what the (or a, if there are multiple best moves) best move is at that particular state.

One thing to note jives perfectly with your analysis thus far: if it's your move, and there are 7 sticks left, you're screwed!  But note 13 as well.

Comment: Nice data. That is really interesting.